# UK PhD application, are there hard requirements on the structure and format of research proposal?

Tags: phd, application, united-kingdom, research-proposal

I am applying to a UK PhD Computer science/bioinformtics program that requires submitting a research proposal. When I check the requirements for research proposals from different universities.

The consensus is that, the proposal will be assessed based on

```
1) knowledge about the research area 
2) the ability to build and develop solutions for a problem
3) proof of critical thinking
```

Some universities recommend (not enforce) standard structure for research proposals. For example, [University of Manchester](https://www.manchester.ac.uk/study/postgraduate-research/admissions/how-to-apply/research-proposal/) recommends having background, review, methods, and
outcomes sections, like

```
Background
  Background -1
  Background -2
Research question
  Aim-1
  Aim-2
Methods:
  Method-1
  Method-2
Outcomes:
  Outcome-1
  Outcome-2
```

I find this structure hard to adopt. For me, it would be much easier and natural to structure based on each research sub-aim:

```
Overall Background
Research question
Aim 1:
   background
   methods
   expected outcomes
Aim 2: 
   background
   methods
   outcomes
Aim 3:
... ...
Summary
```

I wonder

1. is formating and structure a mandatory thing?
2. will my own structure work?
3. I find it hard to put all background and methods in one place. To me it makes more sense to link the method to the corresponding background. Is it because I haven't build a nice connection across different research aims or it's totally okay?

Comment: Expectations may vary depending on discipline. Could you give some indication of the area? e.g. lab sciences, social sciences, history/literature, mathematics/CS...

Comment: @YemonChoi It's bioinformatics and computer science.